# Elasticsearch ignores character "à"

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a text field in Elasticsearch and am doing the following POST query on http://localhost:9200/_search:

```
    {
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text": "città"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "number_of_fragments": 1,
    "fields": {
      "text": {
        "pre_tags": "<em>",
        "post_tags": "</em>"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem I got is that the highlight response contains results like this:

```
In italian city is called <em>citt</em>à and so here...
```

The "à" character is not included in the  tag... What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

EDIT
As requested, here's my mapping. At this point I think the problem is the analyzer...

```
{
  "MYINDEX": {
    "mappings": {
      "document": {
        "properties": {

          ...OTHER STUFF...

          "text": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "pattern"
          },
          "user": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: could you provide us with the relevant part of your mapping ? Especially the "text" field analyzer ? Does the analyzer uses the ascii folding filter ?

Comment: Ciao Decadenza, could you post your mapping? GET <nome_indice>/_mappings ?

Comment: Yep, the problem was the pattern analyzer indeed. Thank you Pierre Mallet.